# No installers found when running install util on custom pssnapin

Tags: powershell, installutil, pssnapin

I created a very simple PSSnapin but when I go to run IntallUtil against the assembly I get the following:

No public installers with the RunInstallerAttribute.Yes attribute could be found in the C:\Tools\PowerShellCommands\SetServerDataSource\bin\Debug\SetServerDataSource.dll assembly.
Remove InstallState file because there are no installers.

However, I definitely have an installer (inherited from CustomPSSnapIn) with [RunInstaller(true)]:

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class SetServerDataSourcePSSnapIn : CustomPSSnapIn
{
   ///
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be carefull to install it with the good InstallUtil.exe. It exists a 64 bits ans a 32 bits.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
```

Versus

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\InstallUtil.exe
```

You may adapt this to the framework in usage in your company. It depends from where you referenced `System.Management.Automation` . On a 64bit computer if you do it from :

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Its a 64Bis assembly.

Comment: That was it.  I needed to use the x64 version of installutil.  It's interesting that I didn't get an error message or something using the x86 version.

Answer (score 1):

When I've done this, I've just applied `[RunInstaller(true)]` to the `PSSnapIn` derived class that defines the snapin.

However, unless you really must support PowerShell V1, it would be better to create a (binary) module and have no need for an installer.

Comment: I fully agree with this, I don't put it in my answer because it look like "Tell me what you need, and I'll tell you how to get along without it." ;o)

Comment: Really the only reason that I want to install the snapin is so I can use the Cmdlet Help Editor: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/02/24/cmdlet-help-editor-v2-0-with-module-support.aspx

Comment: @devlife Sounds like a reasonable reason... but that link says the tool has been updated to support modules as well as snapins.

Comment: @Richard I know it does!  However, it wasn't working for the module either.  It has been made open source so I'm gonna debug and see what the issue is.